# How do I create an accumulator in C++ using a user defined function?

Tags: c++, accumulator

I am trying to keep a running total of cups of coffee sold and I have to use a user defined function to do it. I have tried numerous variations of the attached code but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong? Also I am a newb to C++ so that is why it looks amateurish!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SM_OZ = 8;
const int MD_OZ = 12;
const int LG_OZ = 16;

const double SM_PRICE = 1.19;
const double MD_PRICE = 1.49;
const double LG_PRICE = 1.89;
const double TAX = .0825;

void amtSold(int &smtCup, int &mdtCup, int &lgtCup);

int main()
{
    int selection;
    int smCup;
    int mdCup;
    int lgCup;

    int smtCup;
    int mdtCup;
    int lgtCup;

    smCup = 0;
    mdCup = 0;
    lgCup = 0;


    do 
    {
        cout << "COFFEE SHOP" << endl;
        cout << "1. Sell Coffee" << endl;
        cout << "2. Total Number of Cups Sold" << endl;
        cout << "3. Total Amount of Coffee Sold" << endl;
        cout << "4. Total Amount of Money made" << endl;
        cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Type a number to continue: ";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;


        //loop through the solutions based on the user's selection
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "How many small cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> smCup;
            cout << "How many medium cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> mdCup;
            cout << "How many large cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> lgCup;

            system("cls");

            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

            //Sale Coffee Receipt Page
            cout << "COFFEE SHOP" << endl;
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "Price" << setw(18) << "Total" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smCup << setw(18) << SM_PRICE << setw(18) << smCup*SM_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdCup << setw(18) << MD_PRICE << setw(18) << mdCup*MD_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgCup << setw(18) << LG_PRICE << setw(18) << lgCup*LG_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Subtotal: " << setw(51) << (smCup*SM_PRICE)+(mdCup*MD_PRICE)+(lgCup*LG_PRICE) << endl;
            cout << "Tax: (8.25%)" << setw(49) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(54) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))+(((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 2:
            //Total Number of Cups Sold
            cout << "REPORT - NUMBER OF COFFEE CUPS SOLD" << endl;

            amtSold(smtCup, mdtCup, lgtCup);
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smCup << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdCup << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgCup << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 3:
            //Total Amount of Coffee Sold
            cout << "REPORT - AMOUNT OF COFFEE SOLD" << endl;

            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "OZ" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smCup << setw(18) << smCup*SM_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdCup << setw(18) << mdCup*MD_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgCup << setw(18) << lgCup*LG_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(36) << (smCup*SM_OZ) + (mdCup*MD_OZ) + (lgCup*LG_OZ) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 4:
            //Total Amount of Money made
            cout << "COFFEE SHOP - REPORT MONEY MADE" << endl;

            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "Price" << setw(18) << "Total" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smCup << setw(18) << SM_PRICE << setw(18) << smCup*SM_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdCup << setw(18) << MD_PRICE << setw(18) << mdCup*MD_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgCup << setw(18) << LG_PRICE << setw(18) << lgCup*LG_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Subtotal: " << setw(51) << (smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE) << endl;
            cout << "Tax: (8.25%)" << setw(49) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(54) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE)) + (((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 0:

            system("cls");

            break;

        default:
            //notify the user that an invalid selection has been inputted
            cout << "You have made an invalid selection. Please choose a number from the list." << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }

    } while (selection != 0);


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void amtSold(int &smtCup, int &mdtCup, int &lgtCup)
{
    int smCup;
    int mdCup;
    int lgCup;

    smCup = 0;
    mdCup = 0;
    lgCup = 0;

    smtCup += smCup;
    mdtCup += mdCup;
    lgtCup += lgCup;

}
```

Comment: Well, the current code uses e.g. `smCup` for two different purposes: to record the current sale to a single given customer, and to keep track of the total number of small cups sold. These uses are in conflict. You need to accumulate in separate variables. Local variables in some function won't do. They exist only during each function call.

Comment: To start, you must decide which variables are "totals", and which are the "current sale".  You seem to have mixed them up.  You should then call the function to _update_ totals when you actually make the sale, not when you report.  You need to pass the values as arguments to that function, not just define them and set them to zero inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you probably know, you're not keeping track of the number of coffee cups of each size that you're selling (i.e. smtCup, mdtCup, and lgtCup).

I'm assuming that these variables mean the total number of cups for each size, you might want to put some comments during the variable declaration step. You'll want to initialise the variables to 0:

```
int smtCup = 0;
int mdtCup = 0;
int lgtCup = 0;
```

As this is a fairly simple program, you can perform accumulation without using your amtSold function, so you can delete that.

Then, in case 1 of your switch statement, you'll want to update smtCup, mdtCup, and lgtCup every time you update the values. Please be aware that smCup, mdCup, and lgCup are used only for input in this program.

```
cout << "How many small cups of coffee: ";
cin >> smCup;
cout << "How many medium cups of coffee: ";
cin >> mdCup;
cout << "How many large cups of coffee: ";
cin >> lgCup;

smtCup += smCup;
mdtCup += mdCup;
lgtCup += lgCup;
```

From here on out, you can print out the total number of small, medium and large cups by calling smtCup, mdtCup, and lgtCup in the other cases! Change smCup, mdCup, and lgCup to smtCup, mdtCup, and lgtCup in cases 2-4. Hope this helps!

Edit: Can't comment, so I'll just say you're welcome here!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KTing! It is disappointing to know I was much closer to a correct answer with an earlier version of my code. I could not figure out why it would not initialize and so I started to get desperate and try things I was 95% sure would not work. I ended up going with the following solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Constant for size of cup of coffee 
const int SM_OZ = 8;
const int MD_OZ = 12;
const int LG_OZ = 16;

//Constant for price of cup of coffee and Tax
const double SM_PRICE = 1.19;
const double MD_PRICE = 1.49;
const double LG_PRICE = 1.89;
const double TAX = .0825;

int main()
{
    //declare and initialize the variables for the individual cups of coffee
    int selection;
    int smCup = 0;
    int mdCup = 0;
    int lgCup = 0;

    //declare and initialize the variables for the total cups of coffee
    int smtCup = 0;
    int mdtCup = 0;
    int lgtCup = 0;

    do 
    {
        //get input from user as to what they want to do
        cout << "COFFEE SHOP" << endl;
        cout << "1. Sell Coffee" << endl;
        cout << "2. Total Number of Cups Sold" << endl;
        cout << "3. Total Amount of Coffee Sold" << endl;
        cout << "4. Total Amount of Money made" << endl;
        cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Type a number to continue: ";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;


        //loop through the solutions based on the user's selection
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            //get the number of cups of coffee from the user
            cout << "How many small cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> smCup;
            cout << "How many medium cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> mdCup;
            cout << "How many large cups of coffee: ";
            cin >> lgCup;

            //get the total cups of coffee and store it as a variable
            smtCup += smCup;
            mdtCup += mdCup;
            lgtCup += lgCup;

            system("cls");

            cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

            //Sale Coffee Receipt Page
            cout << "COFFEE SHOP" << endl;
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "Price" << setw(18) << "Total" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smCup << setw(18) << SM_PRICE << setw(18) << smCup*SM_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdCup << setw(18) << MD_PRICE << setw(18) << mdCup*MD_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgCup << setw(18) << LG_PRICE << setw(18) << lgCup*LG_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Subtotal: " << setw(51) << (smCup*SM_PRICE)+(mdCup*MD_PRICE)+(lgCup*LG_PRICE) << endl;
            cout << "Tax: (8.25%)" << setw(49) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(54) << ((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))+(((smCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 2:
            //Total Number of Cups Sold
            cout << "REPORT - NUMBER OF COFFEE CUPS SOLD" << endl;
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smtCup << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdtCup << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgtCup << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 3:
            //Total Amount of Coffee Sold
            cout << "REPORT - AMOUNT OF COFFEE SOLD" << endl;
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "OZ" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smtCup << setw(18) << smtCup*SM_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdtCup << setw(18) << mdtCup*MD_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgtCup << setw(18) << lgtCup*LG_OZ << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(36) << (smtCup*SM_OZ) + (mdtCup*MD_OZ) + (lgtCup*LG_OZ) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 4:
            //Total Amount of Money made
            cout << "COFFEE SHOP - REPORT MONEY MADE" << endl;
            cout << "SIZE" << setw(21) << "Number" << setw(18) << "Price" << setw(18) << "Total" << endl;
            cout << "Small: " << setw(18) << smtCup << setw(18) << SM_PRICE << setw(18) << smtCup*SM_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Medium: " << setw(17) << mdtCup << setw(18) << MD_PRICE << setw(18) << mdtCup*MD_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Large: " << setw(18) << lgtCup << setw(18) << LG_PRICE << setw(18) << lgtCup*LG_PRICE << endl;
            cout << "Subtotal: " << setw(51) << (smtCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdtCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgtCup*LG_PRICE) << endl;
            cout << "Tax: (8.25%)" << setw(49) << ((smtCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdtCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgtCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX << endl;
            cout << "Total: " << setw(54) << ((smtCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdtCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgtCup*LG_PRICE)) + (((smtCup*SM_PRICE) + (mdtCup*MD_PRICE) + (lgtCup*LG_PRICE))*TAX) << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;

            break;

        case 0:

            system("cls");

            break;

        default:
            //notify the user that an invalid selection has been inputted
            cout << "You have made an invalid selection. Please choose a number from the list." << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }

    //loop through if the user is still making a valid selection
    } while (selection != 0);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```